# Sort products by alphabets first and numbers last on listing page

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, sorting

By default Magento has sorting by Name ASC OR DESC.

In my case, I have products names starting with numbers and Alphabets like Below and currently my product listing page lists products in this order.

**.8" stand for all

07" to 09" stand for all

Madame First

Alexander First**

I Need my output on the Product listings page to be like below.

**Alexander First

Madame First

.8" stand for all

07" to 09" stand for all**

After searching for a way in MYSQL, I have found that we need to use REGEX in ORDER BY.

I don't know how to use this in Magento 1.8.1. Can Any one suggest a good solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**File**: app\code\local\Amasty\Sorting\Block\Catalog\Product\List\Toolbar.php (extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar)

**Method**: setCollection

```
    parent::setCollection($collection);   

    if ($this->getCurrentOrder() != 'name'){
        continue;
    }


    $select = $collection->getSelect();

    $field = new Zend_Db_Expr("name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]' DESC");
    $select->order($field);

    // move to the first position
    $orders = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    if (count($orders) > 1){
        $last = array_pop($orders);
        array_unshift($orders, $last);
        $select->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER, $orders); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Working just like I Expected. I would be helpful if you can explain the (if) condition. Why we need to move to first position ?

Comment: it's because we are modifying the ready SQL query (collection), that already has `order by` part set to sort by name.  Now we want to add additional sorting *before* name.